# parse xml with namespace

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I have this xml, and i wish to know how to parse it, I cannot load it because there is error with namespace, but I can load it by using `file_get_contents()`, can you help me how to print out text between dtt:jmn please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<are:Ares_odpovedi vystup_format="XML" odpoved_typ="es" Id="ares" odpoved_datum_cas="2014-03-30T17:47:19" xsi:schemaLocation="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_es/v_1.0.0 http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_es/v_1.0.0/ares_answer_es.xsd">
  <are:Odpoved>
    <dtt:V>
      <dtt:S>
        <dtt:ico>bla bla</dtt:ico>
        <dtt:pf>bla bla</dtt:pf>
        <dtt:ojm>bla bla</dtt:ojm>
        <dtt:jmn>bla bla</dtt:jmn>
        <dtt:or>bla bla</dtt:or>
        <dtt:res>0</dtt:res>
        <dtt:ros>0</dtt:ros>
      </dtt:S> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document has elements with namespace prefix in their names, yet there are no namespace declarations. Therefore the document is not (namespace) well formed and it cannot be processed as XML.

Namespaces are a fundamental concept in XML. If you are not familiar with namespaces, please take time to learn and understand them.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. That is what I am trying to evade. I can read it with file_get_contents(), but don't know how to loop it so as to squeeze this information. Any ideas please?

Comment: Yes, fix your document to well formed XML and use proper XML libraries.